# Unix command to replace first column of a .csv file

Tags: unix, awk, gsub

I want a unix command (that I will call in a ControlM job) that changes the value of the first column of my .csv file (not the header line), with the date of the previous day (expected format : `YYYY-MM-DD`).

I tried many commands but none of them do want I want :

```
tmp=$(mktemp) && awk -F\| -v val=`date -d yesterday +%F` 'NR>1 {gsub($1,val)}' file.csv > "$tmp" && mv "$tmp" file.csv
```

or :

```
awk -F\| -v val=`date -d yesterday +%F` '{gsub($1, val)}1' file.csv
```

even tried gensub but not working.

Example of what I want :
Input :

```
VALUE_DATE;TRADE_DATE;DESCR1;DESCR2
2019-03-05;2017-11-15;BRIDGE;HELLO
2019-03-05;2018-03-17;WORK;DATA
```

Output I want (as today is 2019-03-07):

```
VALUE_DATE;TRADE_DATE;DESCR1;DESCR2
2019-03-06;2017-11-15;BRIDGE;HELLO
2019-03-06;2018-03-17;WORK;DATA
```

Can you help please and give me examples of commands that should work, I'm not finding a solution.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Welcome to SO, it is recommended to wrap your samples/codes in CODE TAGS, you could do it by using `{}` button while editing your post.Thanks to jxc who has done it for this one but please make a note for future posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please try following first?(not saving output into `file.csv` itself it will print output on terminal once happy then you could use answer 
 provided at last of this post)

```
awk -v val=$(date -d yesterday +%F) 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"}FNR>1{$1=val} 1' file.csv
```

***Problems identified in OP's code(and fixed in my suggestion):***

1- Use of backtick is depreciated now to save shell variable's values, so instead use `val=$(date....)` for declaring awk's variable named `val`.

2- Use of `-F`, you have set your field separator as `\|` which is pipe but when we see your provided sample Input_file carefully it is delimited with `;`(semi colon) NOT `|` so that is also one of the reason why it is not reflecting in output.

3- Since use of `gsub($1,val)`, replaces whole line to only with value of variable val 
 because 
 syntax of gsub is something like: `gsub(your_regex/value_needs_to_be_replaced,"new_value"/variable_which_should_be_there_after_replacement,current_line/variable)`. Since you have defined wrong field separator so whole line being treated as `$1` and thus when you print it by doing `awk -F\| -v val=$(date -d yesterday +%F) 'NR>1 {gsub($1,val)} 1' file.csv` it will only print previous dates.

4- 4th and main issue is you have NOT printed anything, so even you did mistakes you will NOT see any output either on terminal or in output file.

---

---

If happy then you could run your own command to make changes into Input_file itself.(I am assuming that you are having propervaluein your `tmp` variable here)

```
tmp=$(mktemp) && awk -v val=$(date -d yesterday +%F) 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"}FNR>1{$1=val} 1' file.csv > "$tmp" && mv "$tmp" file.csv
```

Comment: This is brilliant. Thanks a lot @RavinderSingh13